# Как работает Git Sync

Tags: git

по информации из гула, команда Sync, вызывает pull, push и update. Но не возникает ли противоречие. Если на сервере и в лок.репозитории две разные версии одного и того же файла, то что с ним станет после Sync. Будет залит вариант с сервера(как в pull), или на сам сервер зальется моя версия(push). Кажется очевидным что эти операции не должны конфликтовать, но не понимаю как.

Comment: Очевидно другое: на любом шаге, в случае возникновения проблем, вы получите ошибку.

Comment: это очевидно лишь вам

Comment: git help sync
Нет справочной страницы для gitsync

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это Вы о gui команде говорите? потому что в консоли такой команды нет и не было. Update - это вообще с svn.

[@a_gura](/users/1439/a_gura) прав. По сути, вначале будут выкачаны изменения `git fetch`(это можно сделать всегда, если только не отключили интернет или не хватает места), потом git попытается применить их (то есть сделать merge). Часто он может сделать их автоматом. Если не получиться, то будет стандартный диалог для merge, где Вам предложат ручками решить все конфликты.

Следующим этапом будет push. Если в ветке за это время ничего не случилось, то он пройдет без проблем. Если же там что то поменялось, то будет снова pull, а потом push.

Comment: операция проходит быстро, поэтому вероятность , что произойдет push невелика

Comment: В некоторый случаях push может быть очень быстрым. Дело в том, что в git есть особый случай для pull/push - когда на сервере ветка не менялась. В таком случае работает  fast-forward.

Comment: пусть я сделал **sync**. Изменнеия залились с сервера, я исправил конфликты. Что на этом этапе мы получаем? - Что на сервере и "у меня" одинаковые файлы. Зачем после этого делать **Push**?

Comment: Для того, чтобы на удаленный репозитарий отправить сделанные Вами изменения.